# How do I generate integer partitions?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have a list of numbers like 1,2,3 and I want to find all the combination patterns that sum up to a particular number like 5. For example:

```
Sum=5
Numbers:1,2,3
Patterns:

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 2
2 3
```

You're allowed to repeat numbers as far as they don't go over your sum. Which way would be best to program this?

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What do you have so far?

Comment: The language doesnt matter, c, c++,c#. I have a way of getting some of the patterns but there are still some left out. I think we need a recursive algorithm to do the job

Comment: What have you tried.  It really sucks, but when learning to program, asking someone to tell you how to do it won't help you.  You need to try something and then see if it does or doesn't work.  BTW we know what homework looks like, most of us went to university and took programming 1, 2, 3 etc.  Post some more information on how you want to solve it including code and you'll get much more help.

Comment: This is part of a modeling were doing for our factory. I've simplified the problem a lot, so if the problem looks like homework its probably my bad luck. I'm an industrial engineer so I need some help with the algorithm.

Comment: @Spence On the other hand, often there is an existing algorithm and you don't know what it's called. In these cases, it helps to ask "Is there a way to do this" because the answer is "oh yeah that's Bob's Sandwich Algorithm" and the asker never could have found that just by googling.

Answer (score 8):

This is a slight modification of the change making problem.  You should be able to find plenty of papers on this problem, and a dynamic programming solution would take no more than 20 lines of code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Answer (score 2):

This might also help: [Dynamic Programming: Combination Sum Problem](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/combinations/article.php/c15409/)

Answer (score 2):

These are called [the partitions of a number](http://bit.ly/Nwh7d) , and your problem seems to impose the constraint of which numbers you're allowed to use in the partition.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is known as a "doubly restricted integer partition." If the numbers "allowed" to sum to 5 were from a set V, then it is known as "multiply restricted integer partition." There is a paper by Riha and James: "Algorithm 29: Efficient algorithms for doubly and multiply restricted partitions"  Computing Vol 16, No 1-2, pp 163-168 (1976).  You should read that paper and implement their algorithm.  Understanding how to do it will allow you to implement optimizations unique to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it recursively starting with the highest numbers first. then, each time in start with the highest level and go in as many levels as numbers.  As soon as the cumulative level exceeds your value, drop down to the next number.  If still too large (or small), immediately return back one level and decrease THAT to the next number down, then to the next deeper level starting at the top again..

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static List<List<string>> Partition(int n, int max, string prefix)
    {

        if (n == 0)
        {
            _results.Add(prefix.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList());
        }

        for (int i = Math.Min(max, n); i >= 1; i--)
        {
            Partition(n - i, i, prefix + "," + i);
        }

        return _results;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code .. it wiil give you a exact answer as you want..

```
void print(int n, int * a)

{
   int i ; 

   for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) 

   {

  printf("%d", a[i]); 

  }

 printf("\n"); 

}


void integerPartition(int n, int * a, int level)

{

   int first; 

  int i; 

  if (n < 1) 

 return ;    

 a[level] = n;

  print(level, a);

  first = (level == 0) ? 1 : a[level-1];

  for(i = first; i <= n / 2; i++)

   {

       a[level] = i; 

       integerPartition(n - i, a, level + 1);

   }

}

int main()

  {

   int n = 10;     

   int * a = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * n); 

   integerPartition (n, a, 0); 

   return(0);

}
```